# Send Message to Websphere MQ through HERMES

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

How do I send multiple messages to Websphere MQ from HERMES JMS Application in one go?
I was successful in sending a single message, as soon as I process 2 or more messages to the Hermes application it fails.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stuck with HermesJMS you could give a try to JMSToolBox (on sourceforge) where you can manage "scripts" to post multiple messages to various destinations